# Trouble importing from module after mix a compile

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron, laravel-mix

I'm in the process of re-writing my electron app with ES6, using Laravel Mix to compile the app JS and SASS. Now the main process loads up the render process fine. Once that happens my app.js loads up and that's where I have my issues. So I do:

```
import { remote } from 'electron';
```

Which causes this error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again
```

Now i've tried reinstalling electron, even though electron works when the main process fires up to begin with. The line refers to this in the compiled js:

```
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(__dirname) {var fs = __webpack_require__(8)
var path = __webpack_require__(9)

var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt')

if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
  module.exports = path.join(__dirname, fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8'))
} else {
  throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again')
}
```

I'm not really sure what's going on, any advice or information would be a great help!

Thanks

Edit: I've tried running it with `--verbose`:

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGVA/AppleGVA-10.1.16/Sources/Slices/Driver/AVD_loader.cpp: failed to get a service for display 3

2017-06-13 16:10:42.383 Electron Helper[47106:766924] Couldn't set selectedTextBackgroundColor from default ()
```

Comment: You're getting this Uncaught Error in the chrome devtools window as part of the render process?  Are you using two package.json files or just one?

Comment: What version of webpack are you using? And did you clean it up with "npm uninstall --save-dev (or --save)" with both with -g and without -g attribute to make sure. Then run npm cache clean. Everything should be clean for sure then. First run the build again to make sure it breaks because it's not installed at all. Then install it back. Just to make really really sure it's not a glitch.

Comment: Try to install `electron` with `--verbose` flag, to provide more debugging info.

Comment: So firstly, sorry for the late reply, I was in the process of a house move which required a fair bit of work. Now ive done a clean install for npm and I've used `--verbose`, however still no luck. I've updated my post to contain the contents of the `--verbose flag`

Comment: Debugging info is red herring: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=641509
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4420

Assume that path.txt exists in your node_modules directory?

Comment: Hi Paul, the background colour isn't the problem here...

Answer (score 1):

Most probably source of problem is that `path.txt` doesn't exists.

`path.txt` is generated while installing `electron` from `npm`. If you are not seeing any error while installing `electron` that means, errors are getting suppressed.

**Troubleshoot:** Check if `node_modules/electron/path.txt` exist. If not, then you have got a problem.

**Solution:**

***Note:*** If on Windows, use native `CMD` instead of `Git Bash`

Try to install electron manually after `npm install` by executing following script

```
cd node_modules/electron && node install.js
```

This may take up a while, since it is going to download electron's full package.